# Why is this string timer for delaying not working?

Tags: java, swing, timer

So I have a string timer that

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Delay implements ActionListener
{
    public void delay(int time)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(500, this);
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

delays for 500 ms (there is no action performed), however, when I call it

```
Delay d = new Delay();
        for(char c : dialogue.toCharArray()){
            g2.drawString(String.valueOf(c),x,y);
            d.delay(5000);                               //here is the delay
            x += 10;
            if (x > 90){                                                                               
                x = 75;                                                                                         
                y = y + 20;                                                                            
            }
        }
```

there is no delay between writing the letters. Why is this?
Thank you!

Comment: `d.delay(5000); //here is the delay` before 'nothing is done' in the action listener.  I don't know why you expected that to work!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Wait, could you specify that? Where do I put that line of code? Sorry, I'm new to swing timers.

Comment: *"Where do I put that line of code?"*  Put it in the recycle bin.  (It is garbage.)

Comment: The `Timer` will tell you when the delay has expired by triggering your `ActionListener`, see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Wait, but then I have no call to d if I remove that line of code. Surely I have to put a call somewhere?

Comment: Yes, but, the `Timer` does not "pause" the current thread.  Basically how you think the `Timer` works isn't how the `Timer` works.

Comment: *"Surely I have to put a call somewhere?"*  If you want more detailed help, post an **MCVE.**  At the moment you seem to be attempting 'coding by magic' - shoving random bits of copy/pasted code into different points in the program, hoping they'll work.  They won't.  Not until you understand what is happening and how to use each of the objects and method calls used.  The documentation and tutorials are a good way to sort all that out.  (But SO isn't.)

Comment: right, figured out the problem, it works, now. Thanks!